# Cannot install MySQL connector/c++ correctly in my ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-error-1064, connector

I followed the instructions given by Mysql but I got an error when I want to test it.

These are my inputs:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
$ cd mysql-connector-cpp
$ git checkout 8.0
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ cmake --build .
$ sudo cmake --build . --target install
$ cmake -DWITH_CONCPP=/usr/local/mysql/connector-c++-8.0 ../testapp
```

And I got an error:

```
Using dynamic runtime library.
Generationg 64bit code
Looking for connector libraries here: /usr/local/mysql/connector-c++-8.0/lib64
Looking for the main library  mysqlcppconn8
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:165 (message):
Could not find MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0 library mysqlcppconn8 at specified
location: /usr/local/mysql/connector-c++-8.0/lib64


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

And here is the document link:
[MySql Installing Connector/C++ from Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-cpp.html)

This is the relevant part of the document.

> To verify connector functionality, build and run one or more of the test programs included in the testapp directory of the source distribution. Create a directory to use and change location into it. Then issue the following commands:

`$ cmake [other_options] -DWITH_CONCPP=concpp_install concpp_source/testapp`

> other_options consists of the options that you used to configure
>   Connector/C++ itself (-G, WITH_BOOST, BUILD_STATIC, and so forth).
>   concpp_source is the directory containing the Connector/C++ source
>   code, and concpp_install is the directory where Connector/C++ is
>   installed:

Answer (score 1):

I also occured your problems. This is my solution:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
$ cd mysql-connector-cpp
$ git checkout 8.0
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
# The problem is here: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE default value is Debug
# so it install .so in WITH_CONCPP/lib64/debug. 
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
# I don't know why the options "--config Debug( or Release)" is disable.
$ cmake --build .
$ sudo cmake --build . --target install
$ cmake -DWITH_CONCPP=/usr/local/mysql/connector-c++-8.0 ../testapp
```